# Are there any jasmine custom matchers for comparing files?

Tags: node.js, jasmine2.0

Are there any open source custom matchers for Jasmine 2 that do the following:

- Test if file exists / does not exist
- Test if directory exists / does not exist
- Compare contents of files to see if they match / don't match
- Compare text string to contents of file to see if they match / don't match
- Test if one file is newer / older / the same age as another file
- Test if a file has a given size

I am not using jQuery or Angular and do not want a library that depends upon a large framework.

My application is written for Node.js, not a browser.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an exact parallel on the Jasmine side; but [`chai-fs`](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-fs/) provides this functionality. You could either create your own Jasmine extension following that template or use that as inspiration for your own simple helpers.

Regardless of what you choose, most things are going to simply wrap the node `fs` module; that is easily done.

Comment: Just looked at the jasmine docs, which do an unusually good job of describing how to craft a matcher. I will write my own using fs as you suggest.

Comment: Great! Sounds like something that others would find useful. You should publish a module when you are done  :)